# Tensorflow Model Placeholder Restoration

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to restore, modify, and reuse a (fairly) complicated model in Tensorflow, but am having some difficulty sorting out how to properly pass feed_dict when using placeholders. The code is below:

```
input_dir = "parallel_win_10_40_conv_3l_rnn"
input_file = "parallel_win_10_40_conv_3l_rnn"
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("./result/cnn_rnn_parallel/tune_rnn_layer/"+input_dir+"/model_"+input_file+".meta")

# # Method 1
# all_placeholders = [x for x in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations() if x.type == "Placeholder"]
# cnn_in, rnn_in, Y = all_placeholders[0], all_placeholders[1], all_placeholders[2]
# keep_prob, phase_train = all_placeholders[3], all_placeholders[4]

# Method 2
cnn_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, input_height, input_width, input_channel_num], name='cnn_in')
rnn_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_time_step, n_input_ele], name='rnn_in')
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_labels], name = 'Y')
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')
phase_train = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='phase_train')

with tf.Session() as session:
    saver.restore(session, "./result/cnn_rnn_parallel/tune_rnn_layer/"+input_dir+"/model_"+input_file)

    test_cnn_batch = np.zeros(shape=[accuracy_batch_size], dtype=float)
    test_rnn_batch = np.zeros(shape=[accuracy_batch_size], dtype=float)

    offset = (accuracy_batch_size) % (test_y.shape[0] - accuracy_batch_size)
    test_cnn_batch = cnn_test_x[offset:(offset + accuracy_batch_size), :, :, :, :]
    test_cnn_batch = test_cnn_batch.reshape(len(test_cnn_batch) * window_size, input_height, input_width, 1)
    test_rnn_batch = rnn_test_x[offset:(offset + accuracy_batch_size), :, :]
    test_batch_y = test_y[offset:(offset + accuracy_batch_size), :]

    print(session.run('fin_m:0', feed_dict={cnn_in: test_cnn_batch, rnn_in: test_rnn_batch,
                                        Y: test_batch_y, keep_prob: 1.0, phase_train: False}))
```

When I use Method 1, I get one error:

> TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Can not convert a Operation into a Tensor.

When I use Method 2, I get a different error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'cnn_in' with dtype float

Both of these errors confuse me, because the definition of the placeholders are *exactly* the same before the model is saved, so shouldn't they have the same type (Operation or Tensor)? And for the second method, test_cnn_batch is an ndarray with float values inside of it. I think this may be due to the fact that cnn_in in the model is defined (according to the error message) in the saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph line. I thought redefining it after might help, but no dice.

What is going on here? What is the proper way to do this? I have read many questions that are related, but they don't directly address these issues.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method 1 is wrong because you need to get the **Tensors**, not the operations defining the placeholders. Since you're looping over the result of `get_operations()`, what you get is operations, not tensors.

our method 2 is also wrong because you're not getting the placeholders in the graph, you're defining new ones which are not connected to the rest of your computation graph.

What you must do is find the **names** of the placeholders and then get them from the graph by name.
The error code already shows you one of the names you need:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value
>   for placeholder tensor '**cnn_in**' with dtype float

You can then do:

```
cnn_in = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('cnn_in')
```

(**Note**: You might need to append a `:0` to the tensor name)

Repeat the same process for all the placeholders you need from the graph.

Comment: Yep, that's it! I did need to add :0 to the tensor name as well, because apparently only Operations are named something like 'cnn_in'.